# Restart Git repo Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, git

For different changes I made in my project, I need to restart Git repo and start with a new fresh version with the current project. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fire up your terminal:
go to project

```
cd myPath/MyProject
```

delete the current repo on your disk - your git repo = RIP

```
rm -Rf .git
```

init a new repo

```
git init
```

add your project to the new git repo

```
git add .
```

commit

```
git commit -a -m "init Project XY"
```

check if the repo is o.k

```
git status
```

Comment: Many thanks, but when I try to init Git again, I got this : -bash: git: command not found.

Comment: ah, is not set in your env...but after the rm command - you can init a new git repo wit Xcode Version 4 or newer.

Comment: init git repo with Xcode 4 : https://github.com/blog/810-xcode-4-released-with-git-integration

Comment: try this in your terminal: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin and run this command: git --version

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried it but it doesn't work, seems that Git is not installed, so I will try to install it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a new empty branch without any history. That way you start fresh but still have the option to return to your previous content. Inside the git repository, enter these commands:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<branchname>
rm .git/index
git clean -fdx
```

After that you are in the same situation as with an empty repository (i.e. start adding and commiting files) except that the history still exists in your old branches.

Note that all files you don't have in your old version will be permanently removed.